# Capturing images with webcam in c#

Tags: c#, webcam, image-capture

I need some help for one part of my project. I need webcam to capture 3 images in 2-seconds intervals triggered by motion detector. Here is my code. The problem is I have three times the same image (the first one).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.IO;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;

namespace pro
{
    class Program
    {
        static SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600);
        static FilterInfoCollection WebcamColl;
        static VideoCaptureDevice Device;
        static int no = 1;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             if (!serialPort.IsOpen)
                serialPort.Open();   
             Console.WriteLine("");             
             serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort_DataReceived);
             Console.ReadKey();            
       }
       static void serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
       {          
             string _read =  serialPort.ReadExisting().ToString();
             if (_read == "ERROR" )
             {
                 WebcamColl = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);            
                 Device = new VideoCaptureDevice(WebcamColl[0].MonikerString);
                 Device.Start();
                 Device.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler( Device_NewFrame);            
                 Console.ReadLine();        
             }
        }
        static void Device_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {           
             for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
             {
                 System.Drawing.Image img = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
                 string imagePath;
                 string fileName = "Image";
                 fileName = fileName + no.ToString() + ".jpg";
                 img.Save("D:\\aaaa\\" + fileName);
                 Thread.Sleep(2000);
                 Console.WriteLine("Snapshot Saved.");
                 imagePath = "D:\\aaaa\\" + fileName;           
                 FileStream fs = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);               
                 BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
                 byte[] _image = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
                 br.Close();
                 fs.Close();         
                 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data source=ULTRASLAN\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=veritabani; Integrated Security=true");
                 SqlCommand kmt = new SqlCommand("insert into _imageler(_image,kullanici_id,tarih) Values (@image,22,getdate())", conn);
                 kmt.Parameters.Add("@image", SqlDbType.Image, _image.Length).Value = _image;

                 try
                 {
                     conn.Open();
                     kmt.ExecuteNonQuery();
                     Console.WriteLine(" Saving image to the database successfull..");
                     no++;
                 }

                 catch (Exception ex)
                {
                     Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
                }

               finally
               {
                     conn.Close();
               }

           }
           Device.SignalToStop();
       }

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your code, but as long as i can see you are using a .Clone method to get the new picture. That could be de cause of all the images beeing the same as the first one. Where do you assign the new frame picture to img object?

Comment: For similar questions, please take a look at http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/